# MySQL InnoDB restoration from hardware failure

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows, restore

One of my server went down due to old hardware failure on a old Dell server that's over 10 years old. I was able to recover the files and got it to a local machine.

I want to restore a `MySQL` instance from `InnoDB` storage engine.

I have `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`, `ibdata1` and `*.frm` files. How would I go about it? It would conclude restoring the databases, including the `mysql` database and all the other databases that were already there? how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it the easy way of starting a Windows MySQL 5 instance and coping the data files over. I was able to mysqldump to get what I needed.

Comment: I couldn't have done it any better. +1 and Welcome to the DBA StackExchange.